# How do I update the path in URL to remove a parameter?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I recently implemented authentication in my Vue.js application using Amazon AWS Cognito. I have authentication working correctly, but I'd like to clean up the URL and I haven't been able to figure out how.

When I authenticate with Cognito I receive a code that is used to get a JSON Web Token. This makes my url look like this

http://localhost:8080/?code=7a1d074c-0d39-4da3-a291-b618b69019d4

Once I get the token and decode it, I then redirect the user to the home page of my application using the following code with vue-router

```
this.$router.push('home')
```

This works, but I then end up with a URL that looks like this

http://localhost:8080/?code=7a1d074c-0d39-4da3-a291-b618b69019d4#/home

I'd like to remove the ?code part from the URL and just have

http://localhost:8080/#/home

I've tried using `this.$router.replace('home')` but that doesn't fix it.

Is there a way to do this using vue-router?

This is the complete authentication section of my code

```
mounted () {
  const qs = queryString.parse(window.location.search)
  this.code = (qs && qs.code)

  if (this.code) {
    this.GET_TOKEN(this.code)
      .then(() => {
        this.$router.push('home')
      })
  } else {
    this.LOG_IN()
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you use `this.$router.go('home')` instead?

Comment: When I use `this.$router.go('home')` it just refreshes the page and doesn't redirect to the `home` route. I looked through some documentation and it appears that in vue 2.0 and higher you use `$router.push` instead of `$router.go`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are able to use it in your case but there is an option to use `mode: 'history'` in vue router to enable HTML5 history mode (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html), eg.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  ...
})
```

This will solve the case with `#` in your URL `http://localhost:8080/?code=7a1d074c-0d39-4da3-a291-b618b69019d4#/home`, so using history mode should clear query params definitely :)

Comment: Awesome, that solved my problem. I was able to get rid of the hack I put in as a workaround. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to push with `object` instead of `literal` (like described in docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort)

For example:

```js
this.$router.push({ path: 'home' })
```

...or even more recommended way to pass route name instead of path:

```js
this.$router.push({ name: <your-route-name> })
```

This should clear params and query (?code) and get what you want :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave both of those examples a shot and I still end up with the same issue. It may be something in the way I have my routes set up. I'm going to try a few things (navigation guards being one), and if I can figure out a fix I'll post the result. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things and I found the following works.

I first replace the state so the URL becomes `http://localhost:8080/#` doing this

```
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.origin + '/#')
```

Then I push the home route onto it using the preferred method referenced above

```
this.$router.push({ path: 'home' })
```

This gives me `http://localhost:8080/#/home` which routes correctly, loads my Home component, and since the page never refreshed I still have my Vuex state intact.

If I try to just do the following:

```
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.origin + '/#/home')
```

This will update the URL correctly to `http://localhost:8080/#/home`, but the route will not fire, so my Component doesn't mount.

This seems to be a hacky way to accomplish this, which still leads me to believe I have something else configured incorrectly or I'm doing this process incorrectly, but for the time being this is working.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Note: Using Vue 3 in `history` mode with Composition API.

```
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'

// put this inside your setup() function:

const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()

if (route.query.username = 'test') {
  // do stuff...
  
  // clear the query
  router.replace({ query: {} })      
}
```